# Finding max values

Tags: graphing-functions

I have been using

```
Manipulate[Plot[{(LogIntegral[x])^(1/2), 
(((x*E^s)/Log[x*E^s]) ((((Log[Log[x*E^s]])^(w - 1))/((w - 1)!))))/
RiemannR[x]}, {x, 2, 5000}, PlotStyle -> {Blue,Red}, ImageSize -> 700], 
{w, 33.34, 40, 0.01}, {s, 43.2, 50, 0.01}]
```

in *Mathematica* to play with the plot

[image]

I am trying to find the max values of `w` and `s` where the red curve is at no point greater in value that the blue curve. Is there a better way of doing this? What would the mathematical approach be?

I am guessing I will have to find the derivative of
$$
{{\rm Li}^{1/2}\left(x\right)\,y
\left[\log\left(\log\left(y\right)\right)\right]^{z}
\over
{\rm R}\left(x\right)\log\left(y\right)\left(z!\right)}$$ where ${\rm R}$ is the Riemann counting function, but am at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed.

(I have started `w` and `s` at a reasonable estimate - but when values become much higher than 1000, manipulation is not really feasible.)

NB My best guess so far at the relationship between `s` and `w` is `s=[N[Log[((w/5) + 1)!]]`, but this is clearly way off.

Comment: If you can tell me how to apply that answer in this case, I would be most grateful :)

Comment: I took Ross Millikan's advice & posted it as a separate question.

Comment: @anorton:  this is a different function from the one in the question you link to.  I think I saw this function recently.

Comment: @ anorton - if not, I would appreciate you removing the suggestion that it has already been answered - many thanks.

Comment: You should show the function with $w$ and $s$ in it-changing to $y,z$ is confusing.  It would also be good to specify what the blue and red curves are.  Taking the derivative of this one looks quite hard-have you asked Mathematica?  You can use numeric root finders to find intersection points.  NSolve will do this.

Comment: Yes - but the point is, I don't really want them to intersect :/

Comment: I have asked what approaches I should take on _Mathematica_ StackExchange, but haven't had much joy there.

Comment: @martin OH!  I cannot believe I did that. :-o  Sorry.  I'll retract that vote. (I was out to lunch, hence the latish reply.)

Comment: @ anorton - thanks, no worries :)